# Print a Pattern based on specific rules in R

Tags: r, regex, tidyr

I haven't used R in a few months so some help to get back in would be great.  Below is a sample spreadsheet I'm working with.

[image]

Essentially if it is a five alphanumeric chain ,I want the first three characters.
If it is a six alphanumeric chain, I want to skip the first letter and get the three characters after it.
If it is a four number chain I just want the first two numbers.

Is this possible to keep them in the same column and print with commas like it started with, or do I need to create a different column for each Job ID?

Comment: It is possible to keep them in the same column, as long as they are listed. However it would be computationally faster if you have different columns for each Job ID. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

It's always better to include sample data using e.g. `dput`.

You can use two nested `ifelse` conditions with `gsub`.

1. Here is some sample data.

   ```
   # Sample data
   df <- structure(list(JobID = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("23D04, 17B51, 1B370",
   "H1B331", "K23D13, 1203, 17B73"), class = "factor")), .Names = "JobID", row.names = c(NA,
   -3L), class = "data.frame");
   df;
   #                JobID
   #1 23D04, 17B51, 1B370
   #2 K23D13, 1203, 17B73
   #3              H1B331
   ```
2. Split column `JobID` on `", "`.

   ```
   # Split column entries on ", "
   lst <- strsplit(as.character(df$JobID), ", ")
   ```
3. Extract patterns.

   ```
   # Extract pattern
   lst <- lapply(lst, function(x) ifelse(
       nchar(x) == 6,
       gsub("^\\w(\\w{3}).+$", "\\1", x),
       ifelse(nchar(x) == 4,
           gsub("^(\\d{2}).+", "\\1", x),
           gsub("^(\\w{3}).+", "\\1", x))));
   ```
4. Concatenate list entries and store in new column `output`.

   ```
   df$output <- sapply(lst, paste0, collapse = ", ")
   #                JobID        output
   #1 23D04, 17B51, 1B370 23D, 17B, 1B3
   #2 K23D13, 1203, 17B73  23D, 12, 17B
   #3              H1B331           1B3
   ```

Comment: I've give this a try, thanks.  If I want to print the result in a new column rather than replace the old column,  would the code be different? Also, I want to do this for the whole column with tens of thousands of observations.

Comment: @Alex I've updated my answer, please take a look. This will work on any number of entries in the relevant column.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I'll try it with the sample data on my PC and then go to the company computer.